# Extracting string from main() arguments

Tags: c

I am trying to create a pointer to one of the main() arguments in my program.
I set up the initial pointer, then I set it equal to the 2nd element in the array, but I get an error when I try to compile, segmentation fault. Does this occur because a pointer is pointing to a bad address?

Here is the code:

```
char *filename;
*filename = argv[1];
printf("The filename is: %s", *filename);
```

I get errors about the pointer trying to cast the argument as an int. Is this because the pointer is actually an integer address value and I am trying to set it equal to a string?

Edit: When I change to "filename = argv[1]", then I get the following error from my compiler:  assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A segmentation fault couldn't possibly occur when you compile. Unless, well, the compiler violates memory safety, which is unlikely. I'll take it that it happens when you run the program :D.

The problem is here:

```
*filename = argv[1];
```

It should be:

```
filename = argv[1];
```

Why? You declared a pointer to `char`, unitialized, poiting nowhere in particular. Then, you **dereferenced** that pointer and assigned data to that memory position. Which is, well, who knows where!

Edit: you also dereference `filename` in the `printf()` call. Remove that `*` :).

Also, didnt' the compiler shoot a warning when you assigned *filename? Making integer from pointer without a cast, would be my guess? **Pay attention to the warnings**, they provide useful information!

Cheers.

Comment: Likewise `printf("The filename is: %s", filename);`. The `%s` specifier expects a character *pointer*.

Comment: When I change to "filename = argv[1]", then I get the following error from my compiler: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type.

Comment: @Kelp: define main with `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Answer (score 4):

You're not making `filename` point to the same place as `argv[1]`. To do that you need

```
filename = argv[1];
```

With your version (`*filename = argv[1];`) you're trying to make whatever filename points to have the value that is in argv[1]. There's lots of stuff wrong with this: a) filename is not initialized and can point anywhere, even invalid locations; b) `argv[1]` is of type `char*` and you're trying to put it into a location of type `char`!

Answer (score 3):

In the statement `*filename = argv[1];`, the expression `*filename` attempts to dereference (find the value pointed to) the `filename` pointer, which is not yet pointing anywhere meaningful.

Change the assignment to `filename = argv[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're dereferencing the char* when you try to assign it, so you're trying to stuff a pointer into a char. And since filename is uninitialized, you're trying to hit some random address (or perhaps address 0x00000000. And your print statement, if you got that far, wouldn't work either: you're again dereferencing the char* (to get a char) and then telling printf to interpret that as a pointer to a nul-terminated string.

Try this:

```
char *filename ;
filename = argv[1] ;
printf( "The filename is: %s" , filename ) ;
```